# Error with HTTP post request

Tags: java, stripes

I have an app with Third Party payment system. Once the payment is successful success response is sent back to the app. Recently we have migrated the app to a new server where the call to the Third party payment system is successful but for updating at our end the third party is facing an error as below:

An `HTTPPost.postRequest.IOException [Error when writing data to url.]` exception is thrown.

The third party is calling a POST method with the transaction details to update the status at our application end.

When I tried to hit the URL with the transaction details with a simple HTML page from the browser it was successful.

Can anyone help me in the solving the above error?

Is there any configuration that's missed while migrating the app to the new server?

The app is built in Java using the Stripes Framework.

Comment: provide more details, do you have stacktrace log?

Comment: Add the code and add the stack trace

Comment: don't have any other error log except the one mentioned above as its a third party system they have only shared the above error message.

Comment: at our end the code is just a defaultHandler function for the ActionBean : http://abc.xyz/user/Payment.action which is being called by the Third party to update the status at our end.

Answer (score 0):

1.Client data cannot be appended to URL if it is POST request.
It can be done only if it is GET request.

2.With most of the Browsers you can track the Network activity. And also check for URL object validity

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.yourUrl.com/"); 
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 
   con.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
   con.connect() ; 
   OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream(); 
   int check= con.getResponseCode();
```

3.`HTTPPost.postRequest.IOException` can also occur if there is anything wrong with server. Check if the server is compatible to receive the data from "Third Party payment system"

Provide more details with stacktrace so that you can receive quick and more precise answers.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: but the same method is working fine in the old server. Actually we upgraded the apache version in this new server from apache-2.2.10 to apache-2.4.10 version

Comment: The version here shouldn't matter, unless the data received is handled. You could better debug the code to get more info. without the log or exact location of the issue, it gets difficult to find the answer.